# Disconnected Network Adapter on VMware - only power cycle solve this

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge

I have a weird issue:

On a VMware 5.1.0 installed on a Dell R620, the network adapter gets disconnected.
[image]

[image]

Hitting the 'D'  button for additional info, shows the following.
[image]

- I tried to reset the iDrac - with no results.
- the iDrac shows the network cable connected
  [image]
- Testing the management network fails
  [image]
- I tried the reset Management network - (ofc, not with hopes but I had to try)
  [image]

But the adapter is still disconnected.

- it is connected to an HP switch - resetting the switch didn't change
- Yes, I did replace the cable :-/
- Dell has already replaced one network interface (this is the new one = previous had the same behavior)
- The only thing that works is a full shutdown/power up cycle - of the host - which is ofc not the solution.
- I am not sure what to look for in the system logs.
- Is there a VM patch I need to look for?

-- UPDATE: I have moved my VM's to another vswitch, leaving only the management network on NIC1 (this was after a restart) and everything worked - after some time (can't say exactly) the same thing happned: vmnic0 has become disconnected (with only the management network on it)

Comment: And you don't have multiple NICs for your management network?

Comment: I'd love to hear why, but I don't have HA, no cluster, no isolated ip, so no, I don't have another one setup.

Comment: Does hitting `D` to get details on the network adapter give you any additional information?  And are the link lights on the adapter?

Comment: @ShaneMadden added info - when it says disconnected - the lights are dead on the adapter on the poweredge

Comment: Call me crazy here... have you replaced the cable?

Comment: And is the switchport also set to auto-negotiate?

Comment: [This is a firmware issue.](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/956/p/19476388/20257071.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue was with a broken/malfunctioning adapter.

Manufacturer replaced it, and it works.

Answer (score 4):

A few quick items to resolve this:

- Update the firmware on your [Dell PowerEdge R620 hardware and NICs](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/Product/poweredge-r620). Firmware updates are [super-important](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/956/p/19476388/20257071.aspx) on server hardware like this. See this post on the Dell forums: [*"DELL R720 & ESXi 5.0 Network Connectivity Loss on Intel I350 NIC"*](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/956/p/19476388/20257071.aspx)
- Upgrade to the current release of ESXi. [The current build is 914609](http://www.vmware.com/patchmgr/download.portal). It's a good thing to do in general. The process is [quick and easy](https://serverfault.com/questions/399462/are-vmware-esxi-5-patches-cumulative).
- Also make sure you install the [Dell CIM agents for ESXi](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/555/DriverDetails?driverId=MMPDK). It's an [offline .VIB bundle](http://vinfrastructure.it/en/2011/12/installare-dell-omsa-6-5-su-esxi-5-dalla-cli/). This gives you hardware-specific monitoring.
- And please use multiple NICs for your management/VM network... even if this is a standalone host.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be maybe because you changed the speed and duplex of vmnic, try to reset it, login in support mode and list your vmnic and see if is 0mbps this mean that you've changed the settings.

first see details with: `esxcfg-nics -l`
So reset in this way: `esxcfg-nics -a vmnic1` or `esxcfg-nics -s 100 -d full vmnic1`

More details here: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004089