# ESXi 5.1 crashing

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I got a ESXi 5.1 installation which is irregularly crashing with a error output like the following:

[image]

The server has got the following hardware:

```
Supermicro X8DTN+ Mainboard
2 x Intel XEON E5606
6 x 2GB ECC DDR3-RAM
LSI 9260-6i Raid5
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you provide more information?  Detailed hardware information would be helpful.

Comment: Added hardware information to the question.

Comment: On the 2nd line, is the "world 3942" the same each time you get the purple screen?

Comment: Currently it looks like you are on 5.1 with no updates.  I would recommend running [Update 2](https://www.vmware.com/support/vsphere5/doc/vsphere-esxi-51u2-release-notes.html) to see if this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're running a *very* old version of VMware. The build you're on, **799733**, is from September 2012. The current build of ESXi 5.1 as of this date is **1612806**.

[You're supposed to run updates!](https://serverfault.com/questions/399462/are-vmware-esxi-5-patches-cumulative) (*[why](https://serverfault.com/questions/479148/will-virtualizing-a-server-mean-another-os-layer-to-patch-and-update-more-work/479162#479162)*)  Reference the **[VMware patch portal](https://www.vmware.com/patchmgr/findPatch.portal)**.

Many people don't update or patch their ESXi installations. I don't understand why. But this is leading to a flurry of [questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/570996/esxi-host-losing-connection-to-vcenter/571028#571028) about [bugs](https://serverfault.com/questions/533283/unable-to-view-sensor-data-in-esxi-5-x-on-dl380-g7/533292#533292) that have been [resolved](https://serverfault.com/questions/580521/vmxnet3-performance-on-linux-on-esx-5-0/580523#580523) in later releases.

Your particular issue is fixed in the following [VMware patch: PR932615](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2035777). There appears to be [a workaround](http://vmknowledge.wordpress.com/tag/pf-exception-14-in-world-12323vmast-12322-ip-0x4180002080946-addr-0x410401501420/) that would require a reboot, but it's best to just update the host.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am going to update the host and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

According to [VMware kb 1020181‎](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1020181%E2%80%8E) you may be facing a hardware or software issue.

I would recommend running a memtest to check that the installed RAM is in order and I would also try another version of ESXi to see if the problem is in the current version only.