# HP ProLiant DL380e Gen8 has high fan speed after installing second CPU

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, physical-environment, fan

Today I installed a second CPU in our HP ProLiant DL380e Gen8, and after booting the fans all went to 99.96%. This causes the server to make an enormous amount of noise.

Could it damage the server? What could I do to fix this?
I already removed all the fans and put them back in, rebooted the entire server,...

I'm running HP_ESXi-5.1.0, CPU is twice Intel Xeon E5-2420 0 @ 1.90 GHz.

This is the current memory configuration:
[image]

(before - after).
Temperatures:

[image]

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but you installed the additional fans that come with the kit, correct?

Comment: Do you have any PCIe cards installed?

Comment: Did you change your memory configuration to match the added CPU?

Comment: I placed the extra fan (there was one with the CPU). This is what ESX is showing now: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/7TLnEkQ.png)



I also changed the memory configuration: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/fZO7y2Y.png)

Comment: @MaartenUreel Do you have any PCIe cards installed?

Comment: I saw your response but I don't have physical access to the server now. Can I retrieve a list somewhere using console?

Comment: @MaartenUreel Log onto the host via SSH and type: `lspci`

Comment: Find the list here: http://pastebin.com/xDjrur95 (I took the second CPU back out by the way)

Comment: @MaartenUreel Only an extra RAID controller. That shouldn't cause issues. You're probably looking at a VMware build issue or HP firmware issue. What is the build number of your ESXi installation?

Comment: @ewwhite ESXi 5.1.0 build 799733

Comment: @MaartenUreel Please see the answer below. You need to update your host and probably the HP drivers... and likely the host firmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading all the software, the fans kept blowing 99%. However I suddenly noted a warning during boot time that fan 1 was missing - I switched fan 6 to slot 1 and the issue is now resolved.

Comment: I didn't notice the error message that appeared for half a second, my bad. I expect the ESX software to show that error to me, or at least that the message doesn't just "flash by".

Comment: There are lights on the server that show system health. The message wouldn't just "flash by", and the server would sit at an `F1` prompt for 20 seconds before starting the boot process if there were an internal hardware problem like a missing fan. So what's wrong? The fan? The fan slot? The motherboard? What if you moved it all back to the original slots? Waste of time.

Comment: You seem to be agitated :) When the fans went 100% the first time, I removed the CPU again and posted this topic. You advised me update firmware, software,.. which I then did, but the message could not appear or the status light could not flash because the second CPU wasn't in place. It was only two days ago, after I updated everything, I installed the CPU again and saw the message. So it's not like it has been flashing for over 2 weeks.
I appreciate your help, but don't get pissed off because my problem was not caused by an outdated firmware.

Answer (score 6):

Things to check in the absence of better information:

- Update the firmware on the server. The current revision is available via the embedded [Intelligent Provisioning](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5219984#!tab=features) BIOS, the [HP Service Pack for ProLiant](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5104018#!tab=features) or as a download [from her](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=5269386&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=swEnvOID%253D4141%257CswLang%253D%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken#BIOS%20%28Entitlement%20Required%29%20-%20System%20ROM)e.
- Please evaluate and list any potential add-in cards installed in the server. HP ProLiant servers can [demonstrate different thermal and cooling characteristics](https://serverfault.com/questions/312021/controlling-hp-proliant-dl380-g6-g7-fan-speed) depending of what PCIe cards are installed. Your server should have several BIOS options for fan and cooling levels.
- Ideally, you installed using the [HP-specific ESXi distribution](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/software/vmware/esxi-image.html). If not, you will want to install the [Offline Bundle .vib files from HP](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=5269386&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=swEnvOID%253D4141%257CswLang%253D%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken#Software%20-%20System%20Management) to provide full platform support for your hardware.
- See which version and build number of ESXi you have installed and compare it to what's currently available via [VMware's patch site](https://www.vmware.com/patchmgr/findPatch.portal). I'm seeing an [increasing number of people who *don't* update their ESXi installations](https://serverfault.com/questions/582088/esxi-5-1-crashing/582092?stw=2#582092) at all. If you're using an old build (current is **1612806**), that could be a contributing factor to your fan woes.

Edit:

Your version of ESXi 5.1 is build 799733 and *predates* the hardware you're using. Update your ESXi, install the HP drivers if not there and make sure your system BIOS is current.

Comment: Should I update from ESXi 5.1 to 5.5 right away?

Comment: @MaartenUreel You can go from 5.1 to a later version of 5.1. The current build number of 5.1 is **1612806**. Moving to 5.5 may not be a good idea unless you're prepared for that migration.

Comment: Allright, final question: should I just install ESXi510-201402001 (build 1612806) or first all the ones between my current version and that one?

Comment: @MaartenUreel See this post about [cumulative patches](http://serverfault.com/questions/399462/are-vmware-esxi-5-patches-cumulative). I'd recommend the **ESXi 5.1 Update 2** package, build #1483097. You can download that from VMware. Don't forget your server firmware updates.

Comment: Thank you, I learned a lot from your help. I patched ESX to 1612806, I will perform the firmware updates next monday and put the second CPU back. I'll mark your answer as solution if the fans behave normally.

Comment: @MaartenUreel Did you complete this?

Comment: I'm stuck at upgrading the firmware - the Intelligent Provisioning isn't working well, I opened up [a seperate topic for this](http://serverfault.com/questions/584606/updating-firmware-on-hp-proliant-dl380-gen8-failed/584641).