# Updating firmware on HP ProLiant DL380 Gen8 failed

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, firmware

I tried updating the firmware on my HP ProLiant 380e Gen8, but I received this error:

[image]

What could be the reason? Could it be because of limited disk space in the /tmp directory?

```
~ # df -h
Filesystem   Size   Used Available Use% Mounted on
VMFS-5       9.1T   7.6T      1.5T  83% /vmfs/volumes/ds0
vfat       249.7M 147.8M    102.0M  59% /vmfs/volumes/2e8e17e7-bac572db-1b37-fee052a17641
vfat       249.7M 147.8M    101.9M  59% /vmfs/volumes/3cb7c2ee-5f4b1198-e18b-5b2c486f9724
vfat       285.8M 208.2M     77.6M  73% /vmfs/volumes/4fc813f8-70eae62b-3849-ac162db23ab0
```

Comment: What method are you using to perform the updates? E.g. what did you do before receiving the error on the screen?

Comment: I pressed F10 during bootup to use HP Intelligent Provisioning. I got to the screen where I could select "upgrade firmware", once I pressed enter to "enter" that menu, the server was working and after some time that error appeared.

Answer (score 7):

HP's [Intelligent Provisioning](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5219984#!tab=features) was a [*hot mess*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118204/hot-mess-meaning-and-etymology). The version of the Intelligent Provisioning that shipped with most of the servers in the past year or two did not perform the automated firmware upgrade process properly, hence the errors you see.

***Chicken and egg...***

The Intelligent Provisioning firmware is not handled by the standard firmware upgrade process or [HP Service Pack for ProLiant](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5104018#!tab=features) DVD. [**It actually needs to be updated independently**](https://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_bd9b6997fbc7fc515f4cf4626f5c8d01=wsrp-navigationalState=idx=%7CswItem=MTX_bd68f366ac3748d6acb0892b7e%7CitemLocale=%7Cmode=%7Caction=driverDocument&javax.portlet.tpst=bd9b6997fbc7fc515f4cf4626f5c8d01&ac.admitted=1395840357099.876444892.199480143). The current version today is **1.60**. You need to get to version **1.40** or better for firmware to work.

I don't bother doing this most of the time. Just download the [HP SPP DVD](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5104018#!tab=features) and run your firmware updates from there.

Comment: I downloaded the HP SPP, mounted it on a USB stick and booted it up. After selecting "automatic firmware upgrade", it stayed at [this screen](http://i.imgur.com/Zo326o7.jpg) for over an hour, after which I rebooted the server...

Comment: Try DVD or .ISO via ILO.