# Unable to view sensor data in ESXi 5.x on DL380 G7

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, hp-proliant, vmware-vcenter

I'm running ESXi 5.0 and vCenter Server 5.0 on a DL380 G7 and no matter what I do, I cannot view sensor data.  I have installed all of the HP Offline Bundles (both old and new revisions as suggested by HP).

The `Hardware Status` tab is blank with an error that says, `Hardware Monitoring service on this host is not responding or not available.` I cannot "update" or "reset-sensor" successfully.

I've tried starting it up manually as recommended by VMware by connecting to the console of my ESXi host and running `/etc/init.d/sfbdc-watchdog` and this fails.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can fix or troubleshoot this issue?  I've tried everything from the VMware KB articles and it's not a firewall issue.  There seems to be a direct correlation to the failure to start `sfbdc-watchdog` service as this relates to the cim service that manages the sensor monitors.  But I just get lost in the weeds when I try to trace it at that level.

Comment: Please post the specific revision level and *build number* of your ESXi. Also, have you rebooted?

Comment: @ewwhite yes I've rebooted.  Build number: `5.0.0, 504890`

Comment: I just tried to do `Export data` from the Hardware Status tab and got some new information: `CimMonitorService.ContactCIMOMFailed`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on [VMware ESXi 504890](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2008017). It's old - November 3, 2011.

Please update to the [latest patch](http://www.vmware.com/patchmgr/findPatch.portal) for 5.0 or really, just go to the current build of 5.1.

Take a look at: [Are VMware ESXi 5 patches cumulative?](https://serverfault.com/questions/399462/are-vmware-esxi-5-patches-cumulative)

Make the move to the new version and try again.

Comment: You are the reason places like this are so wonderful!  I spent 2 days between hp and vmware trying to figure this out and this very simple suggestion was the fix to my problem.  What a shame!  Thanks so much.

Comment: @inquisitor Which version did you patch or upgrade to?

Comment: The latest 5.1 available.