# Physical switch not learning MAC address of virtual machines

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, arp

I have a virtual environment running vSphere 5.1. I have two ESXis with a vDS between them. There is, for the purposes of the discussion, just one portgroup on that vDS configured to use a VLAN. The uplink of each host is made of two teamed NICs, which are both connected to the same physical switch. On another port of the physical switch there is a firewall with one leg in the same VLAN as the portgroup.

I have observed that occasionally, when creating and starting a new VM on host1, the switch will not learn this VM's MAC address (even if I force a gratuitous ARP using arping). When this happens, the VM will not be able to communicate with the firewall, or even with other VMs (that use the same portgroup) on host2. However, it can still communicate with other VMs on host1 that are connected to the same portgroup.

Furthermore, if there is a VM on host1 that is working fine and can communicate externally, and I vMotion it to host2, then the switch will not learn that the MAC address has moved to a different port (again, even after I issue arping from the VM), and as a result this VM will lose connectivity to the firewall.

To add to the confusion, and this is just driving me crazy, if I run a "ping -t " from the firewall, *while* a VM is starting up, then the switch *will* learn the VM's MAC address and the VM will be able to communicate.

The "notify switches" option is turned on both at the portgroup and the uplink.

What could I be missing here? I am willing to consider crazy ideas. Tomorrow I will try rebooting the hosts just in case the vDS configuration is out of sync...

Comment: Please provide details about the hosts, ESXi patch level and switching equipment involved...

Comment: @ewwhite Hosts are running ESXi 5.1 build 838463. I'll have to get back to you about the switching equipment. Are you implying this could be a hardware issue in the switch?

Comment: No, just need to know the switch make/model to help troubleshoot. Cisco != HP Procuve != Linksys.

Comment: @ewwhite Definitely Cisco, this much I can say. Did you have specific troubleshooting steps in mind? I'd be happy to try them tomorrow...

Comment: I'm inclined to think this is some kind of problem with the switch, actually... sounds like packets are going though the port without the MAC being learned, which would definitely be a problem with the switch. Can you check whether that's happening?

Comment: @ShaneMadden I agree - the switch can definitely be at fault here. I am not sure, though, how I can isolated the problem to the switch and rule out the vDS. It seems that the only way to do this is sniff the traffic on the switch itself, no?

Comment: @telewin Yeah, or if that's not convenient then you can sniff somewhere else like a firewall or router - send a packet that would go to the device, and if it does show up at the device you can assume that it made it through the switch.. then you can look at the switch's mac address table to determine whether it was learned properly.  The other thing that might be interesting to check for would be if traffic bound for the VM is properly being flooded out all ports in the vlan - if the MAC isn't learned then the traffic ought to flood.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Physical switch it was!

Comment: @telewin Awesome, glad you tracked it down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, this turned out to be a physical switch issue. There's a very long thread at https://communities.vmware.com/thread/421560 that proved immensely helpful (if only by showing us that we were not alone in this...).

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

My advice to you is to upgrade your ESXi installations. Things like this sometimes fall into the bug category, and according to [VMware](https://www.vmware.com/patchmgr/findPatch.portal), your build number (**838463**) is from October 2012. The current release is build **1312873**.

It makes sense to patch if you can, since you're working with a very old build.

Also see: [Are VMware ESXi 5 patches cumulative?](https://serverfault.com/questions/399462/are-vmware-esxi-5-patches-cumulative)