# Can't connect to ESXi 5.x with vSphere Client but I can access the ESXi over SSH

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vsphere-client

Can't connect to ESXi 5.x with vSphere Client but I can access the ESXi over SSH.

I'm not use vCenter, i trying connect directly. When i run services.sh restart then all is ok, and i can connect. After 1-2 days this problem is back, and this is repeated regularly.

Comment: What specific version and build number of ESXi are you running? 5.x could mean 5.1 or 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest upgrading your ESXi to a newer patch revision. Seeing as you're not using vSphere, you probably haven't [upgraded to newer patch revisions](https://serverfault.com/questions/399462/are-vmware-esxi-5-patches-cumulative).

[It's easy to do](https://communities.vmware.com/people/vmroyale/blog/2011/09/15/updating-esxi-5--single-use-esxcli-how-to). See if it resolves this issue.

Edit:

You're using VERY OLD builds of VMware. [See this patch and revision chart](http://www.virten.net/vmware/esxi-release-build-number-history/). We can't even begin to troubleshoot your issues until you take care of your systems. 5.0.0 probably shouldn't even be used anymore, but **2000308** is the current build of 5.0.0. The **469512** build you're using is from 2011 and has been updated SEVENTEEN times...

Same thing for your 5.1.0 installation. The current revision for 5.1.0 is **2000251** instead of the **799733** you have.

For 5.5, you're using an unpatched build **1331820** - The current build is **1892794**.

There are many bugs and issues that have been resolved over the years. So updating is a good thing to do.

Obviously `/sbin/services.sh restart` works for the moment, but I don't know that it's worth digging deeper when we know that the versions are so out-of-date.

Comment: The problem appears to ESXi 5.1, 5.1U1, 5.5. It's too much of a coincidence that the update was required. 

Servers will continue to function for a long time, and the problem appears only recently.

Comment: Please provide the build number of your ESXi installation.

Comment: 5.0.0 469512  ||  5.1.0 799733 || 5.5.0 1331820

Comment: @Mateusz See my edit above.

Comment: Ok, i try :) This is big challenge, because we have 50 ESXi servers :)