# vCenter baseline patch detail ouput

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, update

Within Update Manager I have a number of Baselines configured that show a number of updates available.   When clicking the content a handy popup shows with all the relevant Patch Details...

Is there a way to copy this information or output the details to a file from vcenter directly?

Comment: Which details are you interested in?

Comment: All of it really as I need to plot the details so the company I work for has a record of what was updated and when, severity etc...  And it all happens to be there but I just can't copy the details.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd leverage the documentation found in the [VMware Patch Portal](https://www.vmware.com/patchmgr/findPatch.portal) for the build number you end up on post-update. Each patch has an [associated bulletin](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2079725) that describes the changes in detail.

In addition, the new build has a [summary of all of the components](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2079725), bugfixes, CVE's, etc.

Also see: [Are VMware ESXi 5 patches cumulative?](https://serverfault.com/questions/399462/are-vmware-esxi-5-patches-cumulative)