# ESXi550-Update02 missing on host with Dell-ESXi-5.5U2-2068190-A00 Image

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I recently deployed a new VMWare ESXi Host with the latest Dell-ESXi-5.5U2-2068190-A00 image. I've just scanned it with Update Manager and it says it has 4 patches available. However 2 of them are ESXi550-Update01 and ESXi550-Update02. Surely this is incorrect as those should have been in the image?

If I'm right and this is wrong, is there a way to clear the Non-Compliant status or will it cause me no problems if I just run the updates?

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest just running the updates as-is. There's no harm in it. If this is a single machine, it will require downtime.

Without going into [this mess](https://serverfault.com/questions/399462/are-vmware-esxi-5-patches-cumulative), think of the ESXi patches as being delivered as a full image.

See: [Are VMware ESXi 5 patches cumulative?](https://serverfault.com/questions/399462/are-vmware-esxi-5-patches-cumulative)

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. I'll just run it to get rid of the message. I guess whoever built the Dell image didn't list the major updates as included in the metadata...