# Patch Standalone VMware Host running vCenter/Update Mgr Guest

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

We are running a standalone VMware 5.5 host server (HP ProLiant) that is not part of a cluster or even a SAN with other hosts.  It has a number of patches that need to be applied to it and I'm wondering what the best way to do this is.  I can use the Update Manager to stage the patches to the host but then I need to shutdown all the guests in order to put the host in to maintenance mode to actually apply them.  Obviously this shuts down the Update Manager.  I could vMotion the host off to another server but, as I said, this host isn't a part of a SAN so it would require quite a while to copy everything off and then back again when the updates are done.

Is there a simple way to apply the patches that have been staged once the host is in maintenance mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would download the patches from [here](https://www.vmware.com/patchmgr/findPatchByReleaseName.portal):

You would apply the patches using the ESXi command line and following [VMware's instructions](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2008939).

In the end, you're basically putting the host in maintenance mode and running something like: `esxcli software vib install -d "/path/to/patch/ESXi500-201111001.zip"`

The [patches are cumulative](https://serverfault.com/questions/399462/are-vmware-esxi-5-patches-cumulative) *(kinda)*, so you only need the newest build number.

Comment: So basically forget the update manager entirely and do the whole process manually?  I was thinking I could stage the updates from Update Manager and then just apply them with the command line.

Comment: For a single host, you end up doing it manually unless your vCenter is living somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks... Worked as advertised.  Would be nice if you could just stage and then patch normally but oh well.  As a side question, do you know where on the host patches get staged to?  Prior to asking the question, I staged the patches but now I should unstage them I guess.

Comment: Good question. I have no idea where they are staged.

Comment: No prob... I'll post a new question and see if anyone else knows.

Comment: (it really doesn't matter too much, though)

Comment: Staged files should be gone after reboot since ESXi is running of a RAM-disk.